# Getting this error when doing a GET request on Angular: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, api, get

The tab1.page.ts should return a list of places by doing a GET request. Laravel is returning a file JSON.

**tab1.page.ts**

```
export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {

  places$: Place[];

  constructor(
    private placesService: PlacesService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    return this.placesService.getPlaces()
    .subscribe(data => this.places$ = data);
  }

}
```

This is the service I'm using to GET the list of places.
**places.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Place } from '../models/place.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlacesService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { 
   }
getPlaces () {
    return this.http.get<Place[]>(environment.getBaseAddress() + 'places/get');
  }
}
```

I keep getting the error in the console: cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Added the JSON structure per request.

```
{
    "places": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "place_id": "coktail",
            "approved": "Review",
            "requested_by_staff": "yes",
            "activities_associated": "get work done",
            "address": null,
            "photo_places": null,
            "id_owner_user": null,
            "created_at": "2021-01-02T14:39:09.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-01-02T14:39:09.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "place_id": "librino",
            "approved": "Review",
            "requested_by_staff": "yes",
            "activities_associated": "get work done",
            "address": null,
            "photo_places": null,
            "id_owner_user": null,
            "created_at": "2021-01-02T14:45:35.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-01-02T14:45:35.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "place_id": "librino2",
            "approved": "Review",
            "requested_by_staff": "yes",
            "activities_associated": "get work done",
            "address": null,
            "photo_places": null,
            "id_owner_user": null,
            "created_at": "2021-01-02T14:46:19.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-01-02T14:46:19.000000Z"
        }
]
}
```

**Usercontroller.php**

```
public function getPlaces(){
        $places =  Place::all();
        if ($places)
            return response()->json(['places'=>$places], 200);      
        else
            return response()->json("places not found", 500);
    }
```

**tab1.page.html**

```
<div *ngFor='let place of places$'>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <ion-card routerLink="/place-details" routerDirection="forward" style="background-image: url('https://oecdenvironmentfocusblog.files.wordpress.com/2020/06/wed-blog-shutterstock_1703194387_low_nwm.jpg?w=640');height: 150px;">
              <ion-grid>
                <ion-row>
                  <ion-col>
                    <ion-badge item-start>Type of activity {{ place.place_id }} </ion-badge>
                  </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
              </ion-grid>
              <ion-grid style="padding-bottom:0px;">
                <ion-row>
                  <ion-col>
                      <ion-card-title>Location {{ place.activities_associated }}</ion-card-title>
                  </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
              </ion-grid>
            </ion-card>
          </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the json structure along with the template code that you are using for iterating? Seems like you are trying to iterate over an object rather than an array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated the json structure.

Comment: You also need to share the template code that you are using for iterating. It is breaking on the template.

Comment: You mean the code that's used on the backend for getting the data?

Comment: No. You might be using the json data to do some iteration on the .html of your component?

Comment: ah ok gotcha, just added the template code at the bottom. Thank you Nicholas for looking into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error clearly states, you are trying to iterate over an object but *ngFor* needs an array to iterate over. Make the following change since `places` contains the array information within the object `places$`:

```
<div *ngFor='let place of places$?.places'>
   <!-- rest of the code -->
<div>
```

*Also, it is recommended to use `$` only to indicate an observable. In your case, it's an array so its best practice to rename `places$` to just `places`.*

Comment: thank you Nicholas! This has cleared the error! Thank you very much for you help. I'll follow your suggestions.

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers!